# IO channels vs reader/writer

Tags: concurrency, io, go, channel

Since Go has channels, I was wondering why the standard library doesn't appear to have been designed to use them for IO as well.

There are reader and writer types for that instead but what would be the problem with using channels?

A function could return a channel of byte slices (assuming single-byte, or even single-bit returns are too inefficient) and take in a channel for cancellation requests and a channel for error reporting.

-The curious Go novice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Channels are a good fit for communicating between goroutines. When a program does something simple, like for example reading stdin, doing something with the stream and outputting the result to stdout - then using a channel is an overkill, unnecessarily hurting performance.

As long as the standard library doesn't provide in some place something specific to goroutines communicating with each other, there's no good reason to model simple operations, like those of `io.Reader` or `io.Writer` using channels, respective to have a channel based method set (API).

Additionally, where needed, the simple implementation can be wrapped in a channel, while the opposite, to "unwrap" a channel implementation back to its primitive is not possible. Also, Go authors obviously like explicitness, leading to performance bottlenecks not being hidden (and surprising).

Comment: So I gather your point is two-fold: 1) channels will be a performance bottleneck in this case, and 2) channels would hide the IO and the designers don't like that. It would be interesting to do performance measurements of reader/writer vs channels to have a grasp of what the actual performance penalty will be - realizing of course that the compiler(s) can optimize for simple cases and optimizations will become more sophisticated over time. Rob Pike has talked about performance optimization opportunities for channels.

Answer (score 1):

I think another reason `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` exist is because they play well at the single thread level; channels are almost exclusively for inter-goroutine communication, or multithreaded models. There are cases where you may be able to use them interchangeably, but they were designed to solve 2 different challenges.
`io.Reader` and `io.Writer` also have the concept of EOF which cannot be easily replicated with channels, unless you layer a separate protocol over the channel - which of course would just be an overkill.
P.S. closing the channel is not the same as EOF either since closing the channel prevents it from being used in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This package of mine implements the wrapping of io.Reader and io.Writer into a channel.

Or, in other words, it creates a thread-safe buffer.

Or, in other words, it is a universal pipe.

https://github.com/latitov/milkthisbuffer